# Lawrence of Arabia: women on the cliffs

Tags: plot-explanation, lawrence-of-arabia

At about 1:40:00 into the film...

When the massed Arabian cavalry leaves the Howeitat encampment to attack Aqaba, they pass by what appear to be women on the surrounding cliffs...

[image]

...who are making a shrill whooping sound.  Ali gives a knowing smile which indicates that this is a traditional gesture which women make when their men go to war.  Or is it?

What is being referred to by this scene where women on the cliffs are whooping?  From where does this tradition stem?

Comment: This is also referenced in Three Kings as something women do.

Comment: @CGCampbell, it works for me. Please elevate your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called [Ululation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ululation), and as explained in the very thorough wiki page, many peoples around the world have used it in celebration and sorrow.

In fact, that specific scene in Lawrence of Arabia was showing that the women of the Arab forces were both celebrating their men going off to war, and expressing their sorrow that some won't return.